# How might I represent a Scala trait in Avro?

Tags: scala, avro

Assume a model like this:

```
trait PayloadKind
trait Command extends PayloadKind
trait Event extends PayloadKind

trait Message[T <: PayloadKind] {
  val id: String
  val payload: T
}

case class Alarm(severity: Int) extends Event

case class AlarmMessage(id: String, payload: Alarm) extends Message[Event]
```

I'd like to be able to send/receive Message[PayloadKind] objects and have Avro do the right thing.  (Right now it's completely baffled!)

What would the Avro schema for such a thing look like?  I've gotten this far:

```
val js = """{
  "type":"record","name":"Message","namespace":"com.tryme","fields":[
    {"name":"id","type":"string"},
    {"name":"payload","type":{
      "type":"record","name":"PayloadKind","fields":[]
      }
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

PayloadKind (and Event/Command) are marker traits.  How can I represent them in Avro Schema?

Answer (score 0):

To model this you need to use named types for the record and a union:

Avro can then figure out WHICH record type is inside the union by name. The name acts as the discriminator for the subclass.

```
{
  "type":"record","name":"Message","namespace":"com.tryme","fields":[
    {"name":"id","type":"string"},
    {"name":"payload","type":[ 
      {
      "type":"record","name":"Event","fields":[]
      },
      {
      "type":"record","name":"Command","fields":[]
      }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How many levels can I take this in Avro?  So ideally I'd like a wrapper around Event & Command to be PayloadKind, and then concrete subclasses under Event & Command, e.g. AlarmEvent, FooCommand, etc.  Can those be represented in the current schema spec?  (PayloadKind, Event, and Command may or may not have fields themselves--may be marker traits)

Comment: There are no limits on the levels of nesting in Avro, but the access would be less straight forward if you nest AlarmEvent and OtherEvent inside of Event since they will then be a field within they "Event" record. For simplicity I would suggest nesting all subclasses directly and ignore the intermediate types of Event and Command. Those are meaningless in terms of the "Shape" of the data so they are not important in the Avro schema. You do not have to have a 1-to-1 mapping in your schema provided your deserialization handles mapping the record name to the correct type.